# Url for repeater control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater

I have a link in a repeater control that I am linking to another repeater control that has paging enabled. The link works to some degree except that it links to a page 1 greater than I would like. I know this is because the first page of my paging repeater does not have a page number associated with it, that is, the first page has the url default2.aspx and the second page of the repeater is then default2.aspx?Page=1. I hope that made sense. On the link in the first repeater I have the following code:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ID", "default2.aspx?Page={0}")%>'>Review</asp:HyperLink>
```

Is there any way of getting this link to select the default2.aspx page if the content it is searching for is on this page? Or is there a way of getting the url of the first page (default2.aspx) to be default2.aspx?Page=1?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("ID").ToString() == "1" ? "default2.aspx" : String.Format("default2.aspx?Page={0}", Eval("ID"))%>'
```

Comment: Thanks codingbiz. I converted it to vb.net code and it worked

Answer (score 0):

By adding the following to the NavigateUrl section I was able to get the link to work correctly.

```
NavigateUrl='<%# If(Eval("MReviewID").ToString().Equals("1"), "Default2.aspx", String.Format("Default2.aspx?Page={0}", getInt(Eval("MReviewID"))))%>'
```

To get the second page link to go to the right page I had to create the following function in my VB code behind:

```
Function getInt(ByVal MReviewID As String) As Integer
    Dim rID As String
    rID = MReviewID
    Dim ID As Integer
    ID = Convert.ToInt32(rID)
    ID = ID - 1

    Return ID
End Function
```